# Multi series bar chart in .NET Chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying multi series bar chart based on "Name" but it's throwing an error

> The chart area contains incompatible chart types. For example, bar charts and column charts cannot exist in the same chart area.

Here is my code:

```
            Chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
            Chart1.Series["Series1"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Emboss";
            Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = false;
            Chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn dc;

            dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "Name";
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "Question";
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "Marks";
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            DataRow dr;
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = "Fred";
            dr["Question"] = "2D";
            dr["Marks"] = "54";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = "Bill";
            dr["Question"] = "3D";
            dr["Marks"] = "66";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = "Rhona";
            dr["Question"] = "4D";
            dr["Marks"] = "32";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = "Peter";
            dr["Question"] = "5D";
            dr["Marks"] = "46";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            var IEtable = (dt as System.ComponentModel.IListSource).GetList();

            Chart1.DataBindTable(IEtable, "Name");
```

and Mark up is,

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="850px" Height="500px" >

                            <Series>
                                    <asp:series Name="Series1" ChartArea="ChartArea1"></asp:series>
                            </Series>
                            <ChartAreas>
                                    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                                    </asp:ChartArea>
                            </ChartAreas>
                    </asp:Chart>
```

I'm looking for an output like,

[image]

Where color bars represents "Names"

Comment: you're supposed to ask a question, and what line is the error occuring

Comment: It must be while binding;Not using debugger because it's SharePoint app.

Comment: @Alison, I have edited my question..I believe this graph is possible.

Comment: @Alison, Let's assume my data is like,

Name   |    Question  |   Marks 
A         |   2D   |   10
B         |   3D  |   20
C         |   4D   |  30
D         |   5D  |   40
E         |   6D  |  50

Comment: @Rishi: Is it possible for you to group you data as follows: Question | Score For A | Score for B | .... | Score for N?  Basically, each question would have all results in a single row.  If so, then you can certainly do what you're looking for.

Comment: @Alison, I don't mind it grouping if I get the chart which I mentioned in my question :). Please advise

Comment: Hi Rishi, any luck on fixing this one?  I followed this one and implemented it hoping I would not encounter the same issue as you but it seems like:

Chart Area Axes - The chart area contains incompatible chart types. For example, bar charts and column charts cannot exist in the same chart area. 
Description...  My chart is almost the same as what is shown in Alison's example with fewer people and different labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely possible and you'll be able to produce a chart that looks like this:
[image]

The following code will get what you need:

**ASPX**

```
        <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Palette="SeaGreen" BackColor="LightGray" Width="654px">
            <Series>

            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" AlignmentOrientation="Horizontal">
                </asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
        </asp:Chart>
```

**C#**

```
        //Build Sample Data DataTable
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc;

        dc = new DataColumn();
        dc.ColumnName = "Name";
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);

        dc = new DataColumn();
        dc.ColumnName = "Question";
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);

        dt.Columns.Add("Marks", typeof(int));

        string question = "2D";

        DataRow dr;
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = "Fred";
        dr["Question"] = question;
        dr["Marks"] = 54;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = "Bill";
        dr["Question"] = question;
        dr["Marks"] = 66;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = "Rhona";
        dr["Question"] = question;
        dr["Marks"] = 32;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = "Peter";
        dr["Question"] = question;
        dr["Marks"] = 46;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        question = "4D";
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = "Fred";
        dr["Question"] = question;
        dr["Marks"] = 89;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = "Bill";
        dr["Question"] = question;
        dr["Marks"] = 99;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = "Rhona";
        dr["Question"] = question;
        dr["Marks"] = 28;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = "Peter";
        dr["Question"] = question;
        dr["Marks"] = 44;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        question = "3D";
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = "Fred";
        dr["Question"] = question;
        dr["Marks"] = 26;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = "Bill";
        dr["Question"] = question;
        dr["Marks"] = 89;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = "Rhona";
        dr["Question"] = question;
        dr["Marks"] = 73;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = "Peter";
        dr["Question"] = question;
        dr["Marks"] = 14;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        //Sort the datatable
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.Sort = "Question ASC, Name ASC";
        dt = dv.ToTable();

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Question", typeof(string));
        foreach (DataRow dr2 in dt.Rows)
        {
            //Add user Names to DataTable table
            if (!table.Columns.Contains(dr2["Name"].ToString())) {
                table.Columns.Add(dr2["Name"].ToString(), typeof(int));
            }

            //Add empty Question rows to DataTable
            if (table.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Question") == dr2["Question"].ToString()).Count() == 0)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(dr2["Question"].ToString());
            }
        }

        // Loop through all columns and questions and then calculate the mark
        for (int i = 1; i < table.Columns.Count;i++ )
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < table.Rows.Count; j++) 
            {
                string questionName = table.Rows[j][0].ToString();
                for (int k = 0; k < dt.Rows.Count; k++) 
                {
                    string userName = table.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                    table.Rows[j][i] = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Name") == userName).Where(y=>y.Field<string>("Question") == questionName).Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Marks"));
                }
            }
        }

        Chart1.Series[seriesName].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;

        //convert datatable to a IEnumerable form
        var IEtable = (table as System.ComponentModel.IListSource).GetList();

        Chart1.DataBindTable(IEtable, "Question");
```

Comment: How do I do the grouping of data as you told. My data will be dynamic and I will create data table in run time. So data table will be something like I mentioned in my question.

Comment: I may have not able to explained my data structure well.. Let me try again..There will be same set of data for each user.. For example, Question and Marks fields will be same for every user.So,My data should be, 

User 1 
----------
Question | Marks
2D  | 30
3D   | 40

User 2 
-------
2D  | 70
3D   | 90

Comment: @Rishi: I've updated my answer with completely new code. It works with the data as you have it to produce the desired outcome.

Comment: Thank you.. Checking your code.. There are two errors line,

1- if (table.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Question") == dr2["Question"].ToString()).Count() == 0) 

Saying doesn't contain a definition for Count 
2- table.Rows[j][i] = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Name") == userName).Where(y => y.Field<string>("Question") == questionName).Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Marks"));

Doesn't contain definition for Sum

Comment: What references have you added to the page?

Comment: Ops. System.Linq was missing

Comment: ,Code works perfectly with Column chart but throws an error for Bar chart.

Chart Area Axes - The chart area contains incompatible chart types. For example, bar charts and column charts cannot exist in the same chart area.

Comment: Did you use the code exactly as I pasted it or did you change anything?

Comment: Yes exactly except following four lines to get bar chart,

Chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
            Chart1.Series["Series1"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Emboss";
            Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = false;
            Chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

Comment: If I just change the ChartyType to Column then it's working fine

Comment: I updated the answer to include aspx code.  Try removing the additional 4 lines you added and then use my aspx code.  It's exactly what I'm using and, as you can see from the image in my answer, is working.  There's nothing else on my page.

Comment: Now I am using exact same aspx code but still I see the column chart but with new SeaGreen Palette..

Comment: Whoops!  I forgot to add a very important line of code to this answer: Chart1.Series[seriesName].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;  Add that somewhere and you should be good.

Comment: These is no "Series Name" in your aspx code, so If I add following in aspx mark up

<Series>
                    <asp:series Name="Series1" ChartArea="ChartArea1"></asp:series>
                    </Series>

and this line in C#

Chart1.Series[seriesName].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;

then again same error as I told you above :(

Comment: Are you sure you have empty <Series></Series> tag ? Because I still get the error if I assign some name to this series

Comment: here is my modified markup on aspx,

 <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="654px">
                    <Series>
                    <asp:series Name="Series1" ChartArea="ChartArea1"></asp:series>
                    </Series>
                    <ChartAreas>
                        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"  AlignmentOrientation="Horizontal">
                        </asp:ChartArea>
                    </ChartAreas>
                    </asp:Chart>

Comment: Alison,Any thought why I can't able to use Bar chart ?

Comment: Rishi did you ever figure out what was wrong?  I have followed this approach exactly and come upon this error:

Chart Area Axes - The chart area contains incompatible chart types. For example, bar charts and column charts cannot exist in the same chart area. 
Description...

Comment: Hi @JordanArron I did same as you did. I got the correct chart, but i am not getting details of colors below chart. Actually I don't know what is the name for that details. Instead of showing such details below the chart can we have it on bar or below bar or as title on axis?

Comment: In order to get  the code to work correctly I removed:

Chart1.Series[seriesName].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;

And added:
foreach (Series series in Chart1.Series) {
       series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
}

This gets rid of the incompatible chart types exception/error and also allows for the Horizontal orientation to work.